# Prometheus Server Pod Suddenly Crashed (unexpected fault address 0x7f911b1795d4)

Tags: linux, kubernetes, prometheus, grafana, alertmanager

With traffic Prometheus server pod getting restarting with below error stack. This is happend when the live traffic of the system. But could not be able to reproduced with the load testing.

Grafana dashboard are used to visulization the prometheus server data.

```
unexpected fault address 0x7f911b1795d4
fatal error: fault
[signal SIGBUS: bus error code=0x2 addr=0x7f911b1795d4 pc=0x23c5989]
{log}
goroutine 17680065 [running]:
runtime.throw({0x30f767a?, 0x6961b5048ab89fa1?})
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:1047 +0x5d fp=0xc08949e8c0 sp=0xc08949e890 pc=0x439e9d
runtime.sigpanic()
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/signal_unix.go:832 +0x125 fp=0xc08949e910 sp=0xc08949e8c0 pc=0x450505
encoding/binary.bigEndian.Uint64(...)
    /usr/local/go/src/encoding/binary/binary.go:181
```